# how to update the lookup field default?

Tags: apex, visualforce, table

I have two custom objects with the fields mentioned below.
1.exam(master object)
 fields===name
2.task(detail object)
fields==amount, emaidid, examname(look up for exam object)

exam object have 2 records.1) Java  2) c++
I am going to create new task records for "Java".
while inserting task records I don't want to choose exam name..It should be default "Java"

controller

```
public class taskcontroller{
    public list<salestest__task__c> acc{get;set;}
    public taskcontroller(){
        acc= new list<salestest__task__c>();
        for(integer i=0 ; i<3 ;i++){
            salestest__task__c ac = new salestest__task__c();
            acc.add(ac);
        }
    }
    public PageReference insertNewItem() {
        insert acc;
        acc= new list<salestest__task__c>();
        for(integer i=0 ; i<3 ;i++){
            salestest__task__c ac = new salestest__task__c();
            acc.add(ac);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

vf page

```
<apex:page controller="taskcontroller">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >


<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:dataTable value="{!acc}"   var="a" cellpadding="4" border="1" rows="3">

<apex:column headervalue="account name"  width="20">
<apex:inputField value="{!a.amount__c}"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:column headervalue="account site" width="20" >
<apex:inputField value="{!a.emaidid__c}"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:column headervalue="account site" width="20" >
<apex:inputField value="{!a.exam__c}"/>
</apex:column>

</apex:dataTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>


<apex:pageblockButtons >
<apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!insertNewItem}"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>


</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: <apex:page controller="taskcontroller">
 <apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection >

<apex:dataTable value="{!acc}"   var="a" cellpadding="4" border="1" rows="3">
<apex:column headervalue="amount"  width="20">
<apex:inputField value="{!a.amount__c}"/>
</apex:column>



<apex:column headervalue="emailid" width="20" >
<apex:inputField value="{!a.exam__c}"/>
</apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageblockButtons >
<apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!insertNewItem}"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>
     
 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `salestest__task__c` instances, you could set a value for the `examname__c`:

```
public class taskcontroller{

    private Id JavaExamId; 
    public list<salestest__task__c> acc{get;set;}

    public taskcontroller(){
        JavaExamId = [SELECT Id FROM Exam__c WHERE Name = 'Java' LIMIT 1].Id;
        acc= new list<salestest__task__c>();
        for(integer i=0 ; i<3 ;i++){
            salestest__task__c ac = new salestest__task__c(examname__c = JavaExamId);
            acc.add(ac);
        }
    }

    public PageReference insertNewItem() {
        insert acc;
        acc= new list<salestest__task__c>();
        for(integer i=0 ; i<3 ;i++){
            salestest__task__c ac = new salestest__task__c(examname__c = JavaExamId);
            acc.add(ac);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you its workin fine. one more question can I hide the exam name column ?

Comment: @prabu You can actually just leave that column out of your VisualForce markup entirely.